# use of comma and datatable decimals

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

in which way the comma is added to separate the thousands, now they give me results like `400000`, but the desired result is `400,000` . in other words, I need the results of these groups to have a `comma` so that they can be separated by thousands

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({



            "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api(), data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function (i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\L,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
                };

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(5)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Total over this page
                pageTotal = api
                    .column(5, { page: 'current' })
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                   // '' + pageTotal + ' ( L' + total + ' total)'
                   '' + total.toFixed(2)
                );
            },

            "columnDefs": [
                { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
            ],
            "order": [[2, 'asc']],
            "displayLength": 25,
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'all' }).nodes();
                var last = null;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function (i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                          typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
                };

                total = [];
                api.column(2, { page: 'all' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                    group_assoc = group.replace(' ', "_");
                    console.log(group_assoc);
                    if (typeof total[group_assoc] != 'undefined') {
                        total[group_assoc] = total[group_assoc] + intVal(api.column(5).data()[i]);
                    } else {
                        total[group_assoc] = intVal(api.column(5).data()[i]);
                    }
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(i).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="4">' + group + '</td><td class="' + group_assoc + '"></td></tr>'
                        );

                        last = group;
                    }
                });
                for (var key in total) {
                    $("." + key).html("$" + total[key].toFixed(2));
                }
            }
        });


    });


<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.4/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.4/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Total:</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Airi Satou</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                        <td>2008/11/28</td>
                        <td>$162,700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2012/12/02</td>
                        <td>$372,000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>59</td>
                        <td>2012/08/06</td>
                        <td>$137,500</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>2008/12/13</td>
                        <td>$100,000</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                        <td>Support Lead</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>22</td>
                        <td>2013/03/03</td>
                        <td>$300,000</td>
                    </tr>





                    <tr>
                        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                        <td>Sidney</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>2010/09/20</td>
                        <td>$85,600</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                        <td>Singapore</td>
                        <td>28</td>
                        <td>2010/11/14</td>
                        <td>$357,650</td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td>Michelle House</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Sidney</td>
                        <td>37</td>
                        <td>2011/06/02</td>
                        <td>$95,400</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                        <td>Office Manager</td>
                        <td>London</td>
                        <td>37</td>
                        <td>2008/12/11</td>
                        <td>$136,200</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                        <td>Singapore</td>
                        <td>64</td>
                        <td>2011/02/03</td>
                        <td>$234,500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                        <td>London</td>
                        <td>38</td>
                        <td>2011/05/03</td>
                        <td>$163,500</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>47</td>
                        <td>2009/07/07</td>
                        <td>$87,500</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Donna Snider</td>
                        <td>Customer Support</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>2011/01/25</td>
                        <td>$112,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my current result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQMdd.png)

I want something like this [enter link description here](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/customRow.html)

Comment: have you tried using the built in number format? https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper

Comment: I do not know how to establish it in my project, you can formulate an answer as it would be

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a [Renderer](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) to display the column value with a custom format.

You can use [intl plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/intl) with a known locale. If your goal is to support USA (which uses comma the way you described) you can do:

```
"columnDefs": [ { 
    "visible": false, 
    "targets": 2, 
    "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.intlNumber('us') 
}]
```

Comment: I do not know where to set that `render` in my code

Comment: @MarcoEufragio in the `columnDefs`, check the [docs](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) or see [example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Answer (score 1):

you could parse your number with the built in `number` helper. it accepts five optional parameters,

1. The thousands separator (required)
2. Decimal separator (required)
3. Floating point precision - 0 for integers, 1 for a single decimal place, etc (optional)
4. A prefix string (optional)
5. A postfix string (optional).

   ```
   render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' )
   ```

this will format numbers like $55,000.00.

from your code, you can implement this when calculating the totals after using `reduce()`.

```
total = api
        .column(5)
        .data()
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0)
        .render(',', '.', 2, $);
```

here's a link to their documentation, https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper

Comment: I do not know where to set that `render` in my code